# Seek overview of the '=>' operator

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm browsing sample asp.net code in an MVC project and need a better understanding of the => operator. Plugging => into search engines is non-helpful.

thx

Comment: How could he find out :)

Comment: thx....i did try searching SO - without knowing of the Lambda connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=>` syntax creates [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), which are small functions.

For example, the line

```
Func<int, int> myFunc = i => 2 * i;
```

declares a variable of type `Func<int, int>` (a delegate that takes one integer and returns another one), and assigns it to a lambda expressions that takes a parameter called `i` (the compiler automatically figures out that `i` is an `int`) and returns `2 * i`.

Answer (score 3):

Yo can search it as **lambda**. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The => operator, as has been mentioned, represents a lambda expression.  This is short-hand for an anonymous delegate.  Here is practical example:

If you want to filter all Person objects in a collection to return only Male people, the Where() extension method requires a Func delegate you could create a named delegate like this:

```
    Func<Person, bool> isMale = delegate(Person peep) { return peep.Gender == "male"; };
    var men = from p in peeps.Where(isMale)
              select p;
```

Or you could use an anonymous delegate like this:

```
    var women = from p in peeps.Where(delegate(Person peep) { return peep.Gender != "male"; })
                select p;
```

The lambda allows you to declare the anonymous delegate using a short-hand, like this:

```
    var women = from p in peeps.Where(x => x.Gender != "male")
                select p;
```

Notice the correspondence between `delegate(Person peep)` and `x`, and between 'return peep.Gender != "male"`and 'x.Gender != "male"`.